# How to start and stop jupyter notebook on dl VMs

Tags: google-dl-platform

I want to make changes to the VM environment (e.g. install a new conda package, or activate a new conda env) and then restart jupyter notebook - but I can't work out how to do that within the jupyter user of the Google Cloud DL Images. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run some code on a running DLVM and restart Jupyter, ssh to the machine from the compute section of the gcp web console. Then:

```
sudo service jupyter restart
```

If you want to do some steps automatically before Jupyter is started at the time you create the VM, create the DLVM using gcloud and specify a startup script as follows:

```
STARTUP_SCRIPT="conda install something"
gcloud compute instances create ${INSTANCE_NAME} \
      --machine-type=n1-standard-8 \
      --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform \
      --min-cpu-platform="Intel Skylake" \
      ${IMAGE} \
      --image-project=deeplearning-platform-release \
      --boot-disk-size=100GB \
      --boot-disk-type=pd-ssd \ 
      --accelerator=type=nvidia-tesla-p100,count=1 \
      --boot-disk-device-name=${INSTANCE_NAME} \
      --maintenance-policy=TERMINATE --restart-on-failure \
      --metadata="install-nvidia-driver=True,startup-script=${STARTUP_SCRIPT}"
```

Comment: Thank you @Lak, 'service' works to stop/start jupyter. I haven't quite worked out how to modify the script, e.g. so I can activate a different conda env first, but this can be done manually once stopped anyway.

Comment: ah, i misunderstood. I thought you were asking how to do this on a running VM. I've edited my answer to include how to specify this in a startup script

Comment: Thanks again - I was really just trying to understand in general how Jupyter is running, and all your notes are very helpful. I think to change the environment after VM creation, the easiest thing is probably to stop the service and just run a new local version of Jupyter if you want to make environment changes first.